# Receiving payment for email

Tags: wordpress, email, paypal, skype

I want to set up a consulting service on my blog (WordPress). It would be really simple:

1. Someone asks me a question
2. I give them an answer via email (or possibly Skype conversation)

However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to receive payment for such service. I can ask for payment up front using platform like [Sellfy](https://sellfy.com/)/[Selz](https://selz.com/), but that doesn't seems like a good solution.

How would you recommend doing this in the least complicated/most effective way? I'm looking to collect payments by PayPal.

EDIT: It would probably work if there was some kind of an escrow in which case both me (seller) and the buyer would be protected. However, it's more tricky to set it up since we're not dealing with actual products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can seperate the auth and capture process with paypal. But i think there are extra fees on this so research it carefully.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/authcapture/

Comment: I was hoping for a simpler solution but this does seem to answer my question. Will look into it, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

You can look at getting reference transactions with paypal. They provide you a small deposit before the service. Depending on time of service you can use reference transaction with paypal to charge them the total afterwords. Then if they come back, within 365 days you dont need a deposit if they want to use the same payment method.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, you suggest that first time they pay in advance and the next time they don't? I checked it out but saw that I would need to set up the code myself. I'm looking for a simple, straightforward solution that ensures I get paid (like an escrow of some kind).

Comment: Something like this, you would need to code yourself. Currently, there isn't a solution that PayPal offers that would allow you to integrate this.

Answer (score 0):

I opted for the following solution, which is the simplest in terms of what I'm looking for:

1. Set up Contact form on the website (someone asks a question)
2. I write a reply and package it as a downloadable PDF
3. Set up the reply on a service such as Sellfy or Sellz (with possibly a short preview)
4. Send notification that reply is available for download

That way, the person only pays once the question is answered and I minimize my risks.

Tip: I'm going to set up a short "Terms of service" to which people agree when sending their question. It will be used as a disclaimer and protection against possible misuse of the system.